# Loop through array several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm creating a horizontal string of thumbnails that scroll across the bottom of the page. These can be clicked and swapped for the main image. It works exactly as I want except that I want the list to be infinite - when the last image in the array appears it goes back to the first and runs through the array again so if someone were to watch long enough they would see the same images scroll by.

Here is what I have that works, but I seem to get lost trying to start it over again.

```
var bookImage = [];
bookImage[0] = "images/book1/IsseyFinal.jpg";
bookImage[1] = "images/book1/35web.jpg";
bookImage[2] = "images/book1/36web.jpg";
bookImage[3] = "images/book1/Oil.jpg";
bookImage[4] = "images/book1/3a.jpg";
bookImage[5] = "images/book1/LegsFinalCrop.jpg";
bookImage[6] = "images/book1/8a.jpg";

function swapEm() {
    var lines = "";
    $.each(bookImage, function (i, item) {
        lines += "<img class=\"thumb\" src='" + item + "' height=\"90\"> ";
    });
    $("#grid_thumb").html(lines);
    $('.thumbs img').click(function () {
        var thmb = this;
        var src = this.src;
        $('.main img').fadeOut(400, function () {
            this.src = thmb.src;
            $(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
        });
    });
};
swapEm();
```

Here is where I scroll them ..

```
var thumbScroll;
var i = 1;                     

function myLoop () {           
  thumbScroll=setTimeout(function () {    
      con_left=(i*-.5);    
  $("#grid_thumb").css({"left": con_left}); 
      i++;                     
      if (i < 1000) {            
      myLoop();             
      }                       
  }, 20)
}
myLoop();
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Make sure to clean up formatting of code samples you post. This one isn't egregious but it's still hard to tell where the lambdas start and end.

Comment: hm.... i don't see how this is looping... Also, your `$("#grid_thumb").html(lines);` should be outside the each, otherwise it's doing WAY more work than it needs to.

Comment: Where are you scrolling them? You need to do that dynamically since you can't just append them infinite times :-)

Comment: @KevinB: I guess `$.each`?

Comment: As Bergi said, you can't append an infinite number of images. You need to add some finite number and then as they scroll into view, update their `src` to point to the next image in your list. For easy looping through an array, use the modulo operator `%`.

Comment: the each is just appending the thumbnails, that's not causing them to show/hide in such a way that would result in ever reaching the last thumb other than from the user clicking.

Comment: Off-topic: why don't you use `var bookImage = ["images/book1/IsseyFinal.jpg", "images/book1/35web.jpg", "images/book1/36web.jpg", "images/book1/Oil.jpg", "images/book1/3a.jpg", "images/book1/LegsFinalCrop.jpg", "images/book1/8a.jpg"]` ?

Comment: @Oriol It just makes it easier for me to read, really.

Answer (score 0):

var counter=0;

```
$('.thumbs img').click(function () {
        var thmb = this;
        var src = this.src;
        $('.main img').fadeOut(400, function () {
        if(bookImage.length == counter)
        {
          counter=0;
         }
            this.src =bookImage[++counter];
            $(this).fadeIn(400);
        });
    });
```